# How to get <input tag> from file path Folder Name in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, filereader

I using FileReader and I am trying but I got only getting FileName and FileFormat.

However, I couldn't  **How to get folderName Soma07**

There are several modules available but I don't know how to make it work in React.

Does anybody know?

Here are the examples I found:

```
      const [fileName, setfileName] = useState("")
      const upLoadImage = async (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0]
        const base64 = await convertBase64(file);
        console.log(base64);
        setfileName(file.name)
      }
      const convertBase64 = (file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    
          fileReader.onload = (() => {
            resolve(fileReader.result)
          })
          fileReader.onerror = ((error) => {
            reject(error)
          })
        })
      }
```

[image]

Comment: "fake path file input javascript" is a reasonable search-term.
TLDR - it's a security feature. 

"According to the specifications of HTML5, a file upload control should not reveal the real local path to the file you have selected"

Answer (score 0):

Due to security reasons browsers don't allow to get file path. JavaScript in browser has no access to the File System.